# Python - Add quotes to parameter in called function

Tags: python-3.x

Say I have a text file containing a list of file names

> file name0.txt
>
> file name1.txt

I want to pass these files names to a function

```
fnames = open('names.txt', 'r')

for n in fnames
     MyFunction(n)
```

How do I encapsulate 'n' so it passes the filenames with quotes?

Comment: fnames are not the file names, they are the file objects

Comment: Built in object? I can't use that as my variable?

Comment: [`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object)

Comment: Yes, the for loop alleviates that, passess contents of fnames to n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`open`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open) function in Python returns a [file object](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-file-object). This kind of objects need to be treated carefuly, as they require to be closed:

```
fnames = open('names.txt', 'r')
# File is open
# Do whatever you want
close(fnames)
# File is closed
```

The pythonic way to do this is using the [`with`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-with-statement):

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as fnames:
    # File is open
    # Do whatever you want
# File is closed
```

The `with` statement will close the file automatically when you get out of its indented section.

There are also different ways to read a file, iterating over a file object for example yields a row per iteration.

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as fnames:
    for fname in fnames:
        print(fname)
```

that will yield:

```
file name0.txt

file name1.txt
```

The extra new line is because the value of fnames is `"file name0.txt\n"`, if you want to avoid this you could do:

```
with open('names.txt', 'r') as fnames:
    for fname in fnames:
        print(fname.strip())
```

that will yield:

```
file name0.txt
file name1.txt
```

You also probably want to remove the file prefix:

```
prefixes = ("file",)  # Add here extra prefixes that you want to remove

with open('names.txt', 'r') as fnames:
    for fname in fnames:
        if fname.startswith(prefixes):  # There is at least one prefix to remove
            for prefix in prefixes:
                if fname.startswith(prefix):
                    fname = fname[len(prefix):]
        print(fname.strip())
```

that will yield:

```
name0.txt
name1.txt
```

They don't have the quotes in the console but that is because printing a string doesn't print the quotes, so you can use them to read the files:

```
prefixes = ("file",)  # Add here extra prefixes that you want to remove

with open('names.txt', 'r') as fnames:
    for fname in fnames:
        if fname.startswith(prefixes):  # There is at least one prefix to remove
            for prefix in prefixes:
                if fname.startswith(prefix):
                    fname = fname[len(prefix):]
        with open(fname.strip(), 'r') as f:
            # Do whatever you need with f
```

Comment: I now get: TypeError: must be str, not _io.TextIOWrapper

Comment: Bingo!! Thank you very much, Sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for n in fnames
     MyFunction("'{}'".format(n))
```

Comment: I get: OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "file name 0.txt\n'"

Comment: must be the \n getting added